# LEDs lighting up while being baked inside a reflow oven

Tags: led, reflow

This is a board with 80 3535 LEDs on it just after completing the reflow cycle in my home-made reflow oven. Why are the bottom corner LEDs lit up? Rather, how is this happening?

[image: LED board inside a reflow oven.]

Comment: What's connected to them?

Comment: That's not a microwave oven, right?

Comment: It’s not a microwave oven. Do microwave reflow ovens exist? Nothing is connected to them which is why the Q.

Comment: @electrophile It would be an extraordinarily bad idea to try to heat a PCB in a microwave oven.

Comment: I agree. It’s a regular oven with resistive heating elements modified to be a reflow oven.

Comment: You say nothing is connected, but the picture shows a probe that seems to be touching one of the pads.

Comment: It’s a reflow oven and that’s the thermocouple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that it has to do with the thermocouple I see touching the board vs. the metal insides of the oven (which are touching the bottom of the PCB).

Insulation conductivity increases exponentially with temperature so a small amount of leakage at room temperature can become quite significant at red heat.

It probably indicates that your oven interior is not properly earthed.

Comment: There are through hole pads on the board that connect to the LED cathodes and anodes. The board is placed on an Alu plate which is again placed on a steel tray that came with the oven. There is a small earthing tab inside the oven which is connected to earth. I check the earthing of the oven with a ground fault tester and it showed no faults. How do I check the interior earthing?

Comment: Check the resistance (at room temperature) between the aluminum plate and the earthing tab. It should be close to zero. That will steer any leakage current out the ground pin.

Comment: Yep that is zero. Now that I think about it, it might be some stray leakage current is flowing through the thermocouple probe through the LEDs.

Comment: @electrophile That's another possibility, but I didn't want to go there first because it gets complicated- if you partially short the T/C you can have the oven grossly overheat.

Comment: Do you think that’s the case here?

Comment: @electrophile I'm a little light on information. If you are using an industrial style commercial temperature controller, no. But there are many other possibilities where grounding the junction is not good.